# How to partially transpose a dataframe in R? (specific column to row)

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I would like to change a specific column into a row where the value of each cell is based on another column.

My dataframe looks like the following:

| Race | State | Region | Decile | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| African | a | A | 1 | 3 |
| Caucasian | a | A | 1 | 7 |
| Asian | a | A | 1 | 9 |
| Mulatto | a | A | 1 | 5 |
| African | b | B | 1 | 12 |
| Caucasian | b | B | 1 | 2 |
| Asian | b | B | 1 | 8 |
| Mulatto | b | B | 1 | 5 |

I want to change the column Race into a row (where Freq determines the value of each cell), so I get the following output:

| State | Region | Decile | African | Caucasian | Asian | Mulatto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | A | 1 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 5 |
| b | B | 1 | 12 | 2 | 8 | 5 |

The ultimate aim here is to compute the relative frequency of each Race per State, Region and Decile but that is for another day

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get the most out of your question, it would be beneficial to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In that way, others are more likely to respond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)

data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 'Race', values_from = Freq)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  State Region Decile African Caucasian Asian Mulatto
  <chr> <chr>   <int>   <int>     <int> <int>   <int>
1 a     A           1       3         7     9       5
2 b     B           1      12         2     8       5
```

Data:

```
data <- read.table(text=
'Race   State   Region  Decile  Freq
African     a   A   1   3
Caucasian   a   A   1   7
Asian   a   A   1   9
Mulatto     a   A   1   5
African     b   B   1   12
Caucasian   b   B   1   2
Asian   b   B   1   8
Mulatto     b   B   1   5', header=T)
```